# Is class member declaration not a statement?

Tags: c#, declaration, terminology, statements

I thought the class member declarations are *declaration statements*. But when I look at the [declaration statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664731(v=vs.71).aspx) from the spec. I found this:

```
declaration-statement:
      local-variable-declaration;
      local-constant-declaration;
```

Obviously a class member declaration neither *local variable* nor *local constant*. So, what is the correct term for a class member declaration? There is no separate chapter for class member declarations *in the `Statements` section*, so are they not statements? if they are which category do they belong to?

Comment: There are separate chapters for [member declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645622.aspx).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes but I meant in the Statements section.

Comment: When you say "I thought the class member declarations are declaration statements" what's that based on?

Comment: @weston nothing, just I always thougth they are declaration statements since they declare members.

Comment: Are you talking of member variables or methods, or both.

Comment: @weston both... that's why I said member declarations.

Comment: Declaration is not always a statement. Strictly speaking a declaration is not a statement but some language mix both concept. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***declaration statement*** can be seen as a subset of ***declaration***. Eventually ***declaration statement*** is the intersection of ***statement*** and ***declaration***.

Now concerning members, you have to know which kind of member you are dealing with. For class you have ***[class member declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645622(v=vs.71).aspx)*** etc...

By reading your comment I think you are getting confused with the term ***statement***. In a language, a statement should be a computable thing.  C# does not strictly follow these rules (many other language also do not).  To enhance the ***declaration statement***.

For example:

```
int i;
int i = 0;
```

Both are a ***declaration statement***. The computational part is the allocation in the heap space and/or the initialization of the value.  To simplify a ***declaration*** is something that will be use in the lexical scope analyzer and/or the linker.  But, a ***statement*** is something mainly used in the bytecode emitter

Going back to member declaration. You could argue that a member declaration can embed computation and be correct. For example:

```
class a { static int i = 42;}
```

Alas again C# is not strictly following the definition and should have named this a ***class-member-declaration-statement***.  But the name becomes silly and not all statements are accepted in class member declarations.

Answer (score 2):

From the [C# programming guide page on statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx),

> The actions that a program takes are expressed in statements. Common actions include declaring variables, assigning values, calling methods, looping through collections, and branching to one or another block of code, depending on a given condition. The order in which statements are executed in a program is called the flow of control or flow of execution. The flow of control may vary every time that a program is run, depending on how the program reacts to input that it receives at run time.

A statement is something that *tells the language to make an action*.

A class member declaration does not itself define an *action*; it defines some property of an object.

This is backed up by [drilling down through the C# grammar starting from `statement`](http://slps.github.io/zoo/cs/csharp-msft-ls-4.0.html#statement); everything under `statement` is arguably an action or an executable line of code.

Comment: :) I hat when language have arguably grammar-English-term-definition. It is very hard to define the terms.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the correct term for a member declaration?

[Class member declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645622(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
class-member-declaration:
  constant-declaration
  field-declaration
  method-declaration
  property-declaration
  event-declaration
  indexer-declaration
  operator-declaration
  constructor-declaration
  destructor-declaration
  static-constructor-declaration
  type-declaration
```

The problem is the documentation you linked to is half plain English/half BNF. I find [this browsable pure BNF](http://slps.github.io/zoo/cs/csharp-msft-ls-4.0.html#class-member-declarations) more useful.

Comment: I don't see why `member` should be limited to `feilds`. But since you have one quarter of what I think is the answer +1.

Comment: @mathk yes fair enough, I made an assumption

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to look at section 10 - classes.  For example, a member function is defined in 10.5 - Methods:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645760(v=vs.71).aspx.

On edit: (added 'for example' to first line), also:

Simple *declaration* statements do not cover the (potential) necessary additional information to *define* a member of class (or struct, etc, as mathk points out).  A declaration statement, as you point out, is defined as:

```
declaration-statement:
    local-variable-declaration;
    local-constant-declaration;
```

But when you look at the definition of `local-variable-declaration`, for example, as:

```
local-variable-declaration:
    type local-variable-declarators
```

you can see why member declarations are special - extra information such as modifiers needs to be covered.  Basically, the *'type'* part of that definition has to already be resolved to an earlier definition (or built-in type).  For more complex definitions (such as members), the grammar definition requires additional attributes covered in other sections (10,11,etc) that do not apply to the basic *declaration-statement* case.  Once the underlying *type* is defined, declaring an instance of that particular "kind-of-thing" is then a *declaration-statement*.

Comment: I don't see why `member` should be limited to methods.

Comment: It's not, for some reason I thought OP was asking about member functions as opposed to members in general.  Was already in process of updating my answer :)

Comment: Now I have to ask you why do you think that `member` is limited to `class member` ? struct member exist too. :)

Comment: I'm not looking for this. I'm asking _are member declaration some kind of statement? if they are, what kind?_